# AngularJS HTTP Get not getting a response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble getting responses from certain sites using http.get.  Every get I do from Firebase seems to work, but many other sites do not, although the requests work fine from my browser or curl.  I have two URL's that provide the exact same data, one from Firebase and another from a Cloud9 project.  The Firebase one works and the c9 one doesn't.

When it doesn't work I get the following response:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://dl-celeb-dp-x2jroy.c9users.io:8081/getScoreboard","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

I've tried HTTP as well as HTTPS for the one that isn't working but I get the same response either way.

I have a fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/9d7mysns/

HTML:

```
<h1>{{result}}</h1>
<p>{{content}}</p>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("https://blazing-torch-1276.firebaseio.com/getScoreboard.json") //Working
//$http.get("https://dl-celeb-dp-x2jroy.c9users.io:8081/getScoreboard") //Not Working
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.result = "Success";
      $scope.content = response;
  }, function(response) {
      $scope.result = "Error";
      $scope.content = response;
  });
});
```

Please help,
Thanks!

Comment: seems like 1st link is enabled with CORS. whether as the other one doesn't have enabled CORS.. you need to unable CORS on server side of 2nd link

Comment: Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) - Enable it

Answer (score 5):

I think the second one is not allowing [Cross-Domain request](https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/). This is what I see in the Chrome console for your fiddle.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dl-celeb-dp-x2jroy.c9users.io:8081/getScoreboard. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I was using Node-Red on my other site.  I found out how to enable CORS and it's working now, thanks!  For other sites where I was having this problem, I assume there isn't a way around this if I don't have access to configure CORS on those servers?

Comment: You can use CURL, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  //$http.get("https://blazing-torch-1276.firebaseio.com/getScoreboard.json") //Working
  $http.get('https://dl-celeb-dp-x2jroy.c9users.io:8081/getScoreboard',{
     header : {'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
  }) //Now Working
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.result = "Success";
    $scope.content = response;
  }).error(function(response) {
    $scope.result = "Error";
    $scope.content = response;
  });
}]);
```